# What is the proper terminology for a device that can accept IP video streams and output that to RF as used by consumer televisions?

Tags: encoding, hardware, cable

More a terminology question than anything.

As described in the headline, I want to locate a piece of hardware that can accept arbitrary IP streams (be they MPEG-TS, H264, etc - the exact input format isn't important since re-encoding is easy), and can somehow output those streams over a coaxial cable (RF) in a way that a normal, off-the-shelf TV can tune to those streams in the same way they'd tune to a regular TV channel.

**This is not a hardware recommendation question**. I just want to know what this class of device is properly called so I can locate it myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special name for something that combines IP de-encapsulation and RF modulating. At least one company markets the device as a [QAM modulator with IP input](https://www.dektec.com/products/IP/DTE-3114/).